# stm32 board threading to query imu sensor data

Tags: c, multithreading, stm32, imu

I am querying multiple imu sensor from a single stm32 board. However, reading these multiple sensors cause data frequency to drop 100ms per each sensor added.
I want to know if there is a way to use threading in my code so that querying can be done concurrently, or wish to know if there is another approach.

```
while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

 MX_X_CUBE_BLE1_Process();
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_MPU_DEVICES; ++i) {
     update_MPU_data(&mpu_devices[i]);
 }
 uint32_t timestamp = HAL_GetTick();
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_MPU_DEVICES; ++i) {
     print_MPU_data(i+1, &mpu_devices[i], timestamp);
 }
}
```

The following is where it updates sensor data

```
void update_MPU_data(MPU_DEVICE *mpu_dev)
{
MPU_Read_Accel_Data(mpu_dev);
MPU_Read_Gyro_Data(mpu_dev);
MPU_Read_Mag_Data(mpu_dev);
}
```

Also, this function is an example of reading sensor data.

```
void MPU_Read_Accel_Data(MPU_DEVICE * pMPU9250)
{

  uint8_t rawData[6];  // x/y/z accel register data stored here
  int16_t tempData[3];
  // Read the six raw data registers into data array
  MPU_SPI_Read(pMPU9250, MPUREG_ACCEL_XOUT_H, 6, rawData);

  // Turn the MSB and LSB into a signed 16-bit value
  tempData[0] = ((int16_t)rawData[0] << 8) | rawData[1] ;
  tempData[1] = ((int16_t)rawData[2] << 8) | rawData[3] ;
  tempData[2] = ((int16_t)rawData[4] << 8) | rawData[5] ;

// Now we'll calculate the accleration value into actual g's
  // This depends on scale being set
pMPU9250->accelX = (float)tempData[0] * pMPU9250->accelRes;
pMPU9250->accelY = (float)tempData[1] * pMPU9250->accelRes;
pMPU9250->accelZ = (float)tempData[2] * pMPU9250->accelRes;
}
```

The following code is MPU_SPI_Read

```
int MPU_SPI_Read(MPU_DEVICE *pMPU9250, unsigned char reg_addr, unsigned char 
length, unsigned char *pData)
{
MPU_Chip_Select(pMPU9250);

// specifying reister address
uint8_t address;
address = reg_addr | 0x80;
uint8_t *pRegAddr = &address;
HAL_SPI_Transmit(pMPU9250->pSPIHandle, pRegAddr, 1, 10);

// reading data from register
HAL_SPI_Receive(pMPU9250->pSPIHandle, pData, length, 10);
MPU_Chip_Deselect(pMPU9250);
HAL_Delay(1);

return 0;
}
```

I have found 10ms HAL_Delay inside a function call MPU_Chip_Select, and another 10ms in Deselect. Although, I think this delay is necessary for spi signal integrity, i.e. not to interfere signals.

In total, I was expecting the board to output data for 8 sensors every 100ms, where NUM_MPU_DEVICES == 8. However, it takes about 800ms to output all 8 sensors worth of data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Threading will not help you much, if you do not know where your bottleneck. 
The readout of a single mpu sensor shouldn't take more than several us/ms, even in blocking mode.
Propably one of your function calls waits a long time for an event to process to.
So you need to check the runtime of your function calls.
For that you can use the HAL_GetTick function to get relative function runtime values (diff).

Comment: Please post all of your code. Are you polling? If not, what does the interrupt look like? I suspect the bottleneck is inside MPU_SPI_Read().

Comment: @mban  I have added the MPU_SPI_Read() code.

Comment: Your update_MPU_data takes three times the device sensor data; assuming for each one you toogles chip select once wich takes a minimum of 20ms then you have a total of 60ms only to do this task. Try to reduce your time taken by HAL_Delay calls at all. Therefore try to read all data at once without toggling the chip select in beetween. Also try to reduce HAL_Delay time in your MPU_Chip_Select call to 1ms. The MPU9250 has according to the dataseet a CS setup and hold time of 8ns and 500ns!

Comment: @veeman is correct. 10ms is an eternity for SPI communication. SPI typically runs in the MHz - there is no reason the CS should require 10ms. Additionally, you need to post all of the code. There are calls to HAL_SPI_Transmit() and Receive() that you have not posted. That is where the real communciation happens and until we see exactly what's happening, we can't accurately diagnose the problem.